# find the best combination of columns in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, combinations

assume I have a large matrix (matrix_1) of 2000 columns. Each cell has a value of 0 or 1. I want to find a best combination of 10 columns. The best combination gives the maximum number of non-0 values per row. So it basically gives maximum

```
sum (apply (matrix_2, 1, function(x) any(x == 1)))
```

I cannot go through all possible combinations since it is too computationally intensive (there is 2.758988e+26). Any suggestions?

For an example take this matrix it has 4 rows and I am only picking 2 columns at a time

```
mat <- matrix (c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,  1, 0, 0, 1,  0, 0, 0, 0), nrow = 4,  byrow = FALSE)
mat
# combination of columns 2 and 3 is best: 3 rows with at least a single 1 value
sum (apply (mat[, c(2, 3)], 1, function(x) any (x == 1)))
# combination of columns  1 and 2 is worse: 2 rows with at least a single 1 value
sum (apply (mat[, c(1, 2)], 1, function(x) any (x == 1)))
```

Comment: How many rows in your matrix?

Comment: 100-200 rows. Depends on application

Comment: Can't you order your columns by `colSums(col)` and choose the top 10? I'm asking because I'm not 100% sure what you want, and this helps me get a better idea of what you're looking for.

Comment: no I cant because there are many columns, that are very similar. They have many 1, but in the same rows. I think my requirement is best understood looking at the function.

Comment: Perhaps give us a 12 by 5 example with expected output?

Comment: No, any combination of columns that produces a table with maximum number of rows with at least one value == 1.

Comment: Does `MAT[order(rowSums(MAT),decreasing=T),]` take too long?

Comment: I have provided an example above. Sorry for not doing it earlier

Comment: no MAT[order(rowSums(MAT),decreasing=T),]  does not work, since I need to take a subset of columns not all of them

Comment: @PavelShliaha Understood you need a subset, but once you have the rows ordered high to low, any subset will already be sorted in order of the "best" rows, and you can select the ones you want. `MAT[order(rowSums(MAT),decreasing=T),]` runs pretty much instantly with a 100x2000 matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a function like this...

```
find10 <- function(mat,n=10){
  cols <- rep(FALSE,ncol(mat)) #columns to exclude
  rows <- rep(TRUE,nrow(mat)) #rows to include
  for(i in 1:n){
    colsums <- colSums(mat[rows,])
    colsums[cols] <- -1 #to exclude those already accounted for
    maxcol <- which.max(colsums)
    cols[maxcol] <- TRUE
    rows <- rows & !as.logical(mat[,maxcol]) 
  }
  return(which(cols))
}
```

It looks for the column with most non-zeros, removes those rows from the comparison, and repeats.  It returns the column numbers of the n best columns.

An example...

```
m <- matrix(sample(0:1,100,prob = c(0.8,0.2),replace=TRUE),nrow=10)

m
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    1     0
 [2,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     1
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0     0
 [4,]    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    1    0     1
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    0     0
 [6,]    0    0    0    1    0    1    1    0    0     0
 [7,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0

find10(m,5)
[1] 3 4 5 8 9
```

It also comes up with `2,3` for the example you give.

Comment: Interesting solution. I have to think about it!